# Second change listener in a Sencha Touch 2 view breaks build

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I've got a Sencha Touch 2 view that's using this ratings class: [Ext.ux.touch.rating](https://github.com/podlipensky/Ext.ux.touch.Rating/tree/sencha2), with two instances:

```
{
    xtype: 'rating',
    id: 'rating1',
    value: -1,
    itemCls: 'x-rating-star',
    itemHoverCls: 'x-rating-star-hover',
    listeners: {
        change: function () {
            Ext.getCmp('ratingBtn').setDisabled(Ext.getCmp('rating2').getValue() == -1)
        }
    }
},
...
{
    xtype: 'rating',
    id: 'rating2',
    value: -1,
    itemCls: 'x-rating-star',
    itemHoverCls: 'x-rating-star-hover',
    listeners: {
        change: function () {
            Ext.getCmp('ratingBtn').setDisabled(Ext.getCmp('rating1').getValue() == -1)
        }
    }
},
...
{
    xtype: 'button',
    ui: 'confirm',
    text: 'Rate',
    id: 'ratingBtn',
    disabled: true
},
```

I'm trying, with the code above, to get ratingBtn (IDs are named slightly differently in my code) to be enabled once both ratings have been filled.

If I only have the first listener attached, things work fine (except no action on the second rating changing). If I attach the second listener with a console.log(this) or console.log(this.parent) or even Ext.getCmp('ratingBtn'), the app builds fine.

But if I attempt to invoke setDisabled() on the element (and this only happens for the second listener...and happens even if I call it as setDisabled(false)), I get this when compiling (plus a huge stack trace):

```
[ERROR] TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object
Stack trace:
    file:////[snipped]/app/view/[snipped].js?_dc=1371009329838 : 346 : Anonymous
```

with line 346 being the line where I attempted to call setDisabled().

I can't find a way (including pushing both listeners to the controller) to get rid of this error, or one effectively identical to it. Even doing naughty things like document.getElementById return null, so the build tool says.

So, how do I fix this issue? I realize that the above code won't win any awards for OOP, but it should at least build...right?!? How do I get it to do that?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the line before `setDisabled` and first try to find the  button in the dom by using inspector. Make sure id is present and button is rendered properly. If everything is fine, go inside the `setDisabled` function and see why exactly the error happens.

Comment: The button shows up just fine in the browser, including the ID...or are you talking about the inspector in Sencha Architect or the like?

The issue is that the sencha build (sencha app build testing using command v 2.0.2) hangs up on the second time Ext.getCmp('ratingBtn').setDisabled() comes around...the first one gets through. It's thinking that Ext.getCmp('ratingBtn') returns undefined, even when in a browser (Chrome) console.log'ing the element gives back the expected class. So I can replace setDisabled() with any attempt to access a property or function with the same result.

Comment: ...and I didn't realize I could test without building. Looking at it not, I do see the error as soon as the app loads. More later...

Comment: Alternatively you may create the button instance before you put it in `this.items` collection, i.e. `var btn = new Ext.Button({...})`. Then, in initialization method you can add it to the collection `this.items`. So you don't have to lookup for it in the dom later, you can just use `btn.setDisabled(...)`. Even if button haven't been rendered the method will work just fine.